# Error when delegating class method in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I have this UseCase class:

```
class UseCase {

    constructor(repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    execute() {
      //do stuff
    }

}

module.exports = UseCase;
```

and this Service class:

```
class Service {

    constructor(repository) {
        this.useCase = new UseCase(repository);
    }

    doWork = this.useCase.execute;

}

module.exports = Service;
```

What I want is delegate `service.doWork()` call to `useCase.execute()`, but when I execute it, I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined

However, if I change my `Service` code to this:

```
class Service {

    constructor(repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    doWork = new UseCase(this.repository).execute;

}

module.exports = Service;
```

it works properly! Why is that? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class fields run as soon after the constructor they can, right after any `super` calls, if any. Your code is equivalent to:

```
class Service {
    constructor(repository) {
        this.doWork = this.useCase.execute;
        this.useCase = new UseCase(repository);
    }
}
```

It's not defined in time.

Put `doWork` in the constructor instead, after the assignment to `useCase`.

You also need to make sure that `.execute` is called with the proper calling context - just passing `this.useCase.execute` loses the calling context of `useCase`.

```
class Service {
    constructor(repository) {
        this.useCase = new UseCase(repository);
        this.doWork = () => this.useCase.execute();
    }
}
```

You could also use a class field which calls `.execute` when called:

```
class Service {
    constructor(repository) {
        this.useCase = new UseCase(repository);
    }
    doWork = () => this.useCase.execute();
}
```

Comment: And at that point you might as well use a normal method.